# Add icon to angular material input

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to add a search icon to my input search bar out of [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.input) :

```
<aside class="main-sidebar">
    <section class="sidebar control-sidebar-dark" id="leftMenu">
        <div>
            <!--  need to disable overflow-x somehow cuz of menu -->
            <md-tabs md-center-tabs id="menuTabs" md-dynamic-height="true" md-selected="selectedIndex">

                <md-tab label="<i class='fa fa-search'></i>" ng-if="handleResize()" search-Focus>
                    <md-content class="control-sidebar-dark" ng-style="{'height' : menuHeight}">
                        <!-- search Menu -->
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <form action="javascript:void(0)" method="get" class="sidebar-form" id="searchForm">
                                    <div>
                                    <md-content md-theme="docs-dark">
                                        <md-input-container style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
                                            <label>{{isEnglish ? 'Search...' : 'Recherche...'}}</label>
                                            <input ng-model="searchInput" id="sInput" ng-change="filterCartoList(searchInput)" my-enter="filterCartoList(searchInput)">
                                        </md-input-container>
                                    </md-content>
                                    </div>

                                </form>
                                <div>
```

When I'm trying to reproduce the example with icons that we can see there : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOxMdR , I'm having style issues and nothing works properly.

Any idea how I could simply add a search icon to my existing input ?

Comment: where you want to add `icon` ? inside form ?

Comment: Well, on the left or right of the text input, preferably right.

Comment: Check I added working plunker in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

As you are using `angular-material-design` and `font-awesome-icon` use `<md-icon>` as element with `md-font-icon` attribute.

And use `class="md-icon-float"` with `md-inout-container`.

Working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FvOnd7T65Pyt7w2petmC?p=preview)

Change this :

```
<md-content md-theme="docs-dark">
    <md-input-container style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
        <label>{{isEnglish ? 'Search...' : 'Recherche...'}}</label>
        <input ng-model="searchInput" id="sInput" ng-change="filterCartoList(searchInput)" my-enter="filterCartoList(searchInput)">
    </md-input-container>
</md-content>
```

To :

```
<md-content md-theme="docs-dark">
    <md-input-container class="md-icon-float">
        <label>{{isEnglish ? 'Search...' : 'Recherche...'}}</label>
        <md-icon md-font-icon="fa fa-search"></md-icon>
        <input ng-model="searchInput" id="sInput" ng-change="filterCartoList(searchInput)" my-enter="filterCartoList(searchInput)">
    </md-input-container>
</md-content>
```

Comment: Yea I tried that but, the icon goes upper in a reduced size, just like the placeholder of the input when we focus the input. You can see the placeholder behavior there : https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.input

Comment: did you added class="md-icon-float" ? like this `<md-input-container class="md-icon-float">`

Comment: Well, I tried that too after your edit, but then the issue is the height of the content becomes too big, and I have a scrollbar in the input content. I would like to have a one line input with an icon just like the email in the last example there : https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.input

Comment: there is no difference between plunker's example and Email input in angular-material site. the difference is only Email does not have label but have placeholder. I update Plunker again.

Comment: Yea but mine gets a scrollbar, it's probably because of one of its parents :

aside > section > md-tabs > md-tab > md-content > form > md-content > md-input-container > input

Answer (score 1):

This question is very old but I just ran into the same issue this morning and the answer from @gaurav didn't work the same as what the OP was looking for in this link: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.input

If you open the Chrome developer console you can inspect the element and see that the guys who wrote the demo code are using a custom class for the icon behavior of the email input in the bottom icons section.  I essentially copied that behavior to achieve the same desired effect.

HTML:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block md-icon-left">
    <md-icon class="form-icon">lock_outline</md-icon>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input 
        type="password" ng-model="user.password" name="password" 
        ng-required="true" 
        ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && loginForm.$valid && login()"/>
</md-input-container>
```

CSS:

```
/* Angular extension */
md-input-container.md-input-invalid > md-icon.form-icon {
  color: #B71C1C;
}
```

One thing to note is that I had to add the class "md-icon-left" to my md-container or the icons would stack on top of the input.  I am using angular material v1.1.0 and angular js v1.5.5 in my project.  I hope this answers helps anyone else looking to achieve the same behavior as in the Angular Material demo.